# Touch through view and simultaneous handling gesture

Tags: ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, hittest

I want several views to handle their `UIPanGestureRecongizer`s simultaneously. These views are not nested, they are transparent and are subviews of common `superview`.

Hit test overriding helps to route touches through a view, but in this case, the view can't handle touch events itself.

This is the common question about the possible delivery of touch event not to single view and its subviews, but to several views. Maybe it is possible from front view to duplicate events to back view.

Just found "Forwarding Touch Events" article. Need to use it from view not window. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/multitouch_background/multitouch_background.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH5-SW7

Comment: could you just attach the pan gesture to the superview that contains all the views? Perhaps explaining more about your problem could help us give a more appropriate solution.

Comment: @JonRose short answer: No. Really only one of this views is mine, second one is not mine - it have its own gesture recognizers.

Comment: did you try `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith:)`?

Comment: @JonRose yep, it just did not work, because of hit testing.

Comment: did you try put the gesture on the superview?

Comment: @JonRose I have some reasons to avoid this. This is just simplified example of what I am trying to achieve.